# How to read a pandas dataframe in Databricks?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, databricks

I don't know why, but my file located at "FileStore/tables/train.csv" is not readable using pandas in the Databricks platform. I tried :

```
pd.read_csv("/dbfs/FileStore/tables/train.csv")
```

and got

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File /dbfs/FileStore/tables/train.csv does not exist: '/dbfs/FileStore/tables/train.csv'
```

Comment: You must provide full path to file

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't understand your comment. I think this is the full path.

Comment: what is the full path to file? I mean if your root directory is "C:" what is path that leads to your file?

Comment: I'm working on the Databricks platform. There's no "C:". The full path is "/FileStore/tables/train.csv". The documentation explains that with pandas you have to write "/dbfs/FileStore/tables/train.csv".

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply.
You can read microsoft docs [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/python/dbfs-file-size-limit)

It will help you in copying the file uploaded in "FileStore" to "Tmp" location.
This should enable your code like:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv(path)
```

and

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps
ps.read_csv(path)
```